# Cargo build command always Compiling dependencies

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Use cargo init to crate the project, then add the gtk4-rs dependencies. Here is the Cargo.toml file

```
[package]
name = "study_rust"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies.gtk]
path = "D:/gtk4-rs/gtk4"
package = "gtk4"
```

Here is the main.rs

```
fn main() {
    print!("ok")
}
```

then I run the cargo build:

```
cargo build
   Compiling glib-sys v0.15.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#693878b4)
   Compiling gobject-sys v0.15.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#693878b4)
   Compiling gio-sys v0.15.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#693878b4)
   Compiling pango-sys v0.15.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#693878b4)
   Compiling gdk-pixbuf-sys v0.15.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#693878b4)
   Compiling cairo-sys-rs v0.15.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#693878b4)
   Compiling gdk4-sys v0.3.0 (D:\gtk4-rs\gdk4\sys)
   Compiling graphene-sys v0.15.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#693878b4)
   Compiling gsk4-sys v0.3.0 (D:\gtk4-rs\gsk4\sys)
   Compiling gtk4-sys v0.3.0 (D:\gtk4-rs\gtk4\sys)
   Compiling glib v0.15.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#693878b4)
   Compiling gio v0.15.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#693878b4)
   Compiling pango v0.15.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#693878b4)
   Compiling cairo-rs v0.15.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#693878b4)
   Compiling graphene-rs v0.15.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#693878b4)
   Compiling gdk-pixbuf v0.15.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#693878b4)
   Compiling gdk4 v0.3.0 (D:\gtk4-rs\gdk4)
   Compiling gsk4 v0.3.0 (D:\gtk4-rs\gsk4)
   Compiling gtk4 v0.3.0 (D:\gtk4-rs\gtk4)
   Compiling study_rust v0.1.0 (C:\study_projects\study_rust)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 44.28s
```

it takes several seconds (44.28s) to finish.

then I modify the main.rs,

```
fn main() {
    print!("ok, the tiny change of string!!!!")
}
```

then I run the cargo build again:
i don't understand why every time run the cargo build should recomile all the gtk-rs dependencies. This takes several seconds to finish even i just change some print string.
There're must be something wrong that every time take so long to build the target executable file.

```
cargo build
   Compiling glib-sys v0.15.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#693878b4)
   Compiling gobject-sys v0.15.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#693878b4)
   Compiling gio-sys v0.15.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#693878b4)
   Compiling pango-sys v0.15.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#693878b4)
   Compiling cairo-sys-rs v0.15.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#693878b4)
   Compiling gdk-pixbuf-sys v0.15.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#693878b4)
   Compiling graphene-sys v0.15.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#693878b4)
   Compiling gdk4-sys v0.3.0 (D:\gtk4-rs\gdk4\sys)
   Compiling gsk4-sys v0.3.0 (D:\gtk4-rs\gsk4\sys)
   Compiling gtk4-sys v0.3.0 (D:\gtk4-rs\gtk4\sys)
   Compiling glib v0.15.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#693878b4)
   Compiling gio v0.15.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#693878b4)
   Compiling pango v0.15.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#693878b4)
   Compiling cairo-rs v0.15.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#693878b4)
   Compiling graphene-rs v0.15.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#693878b4)
   Compiling gdk-pixbuf v0.15.0 (https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk-rs-core#693878b4)
   Compiling gdk4 v0.3.0 (D:\gtk4-rs\gdk4)
   Compiling gsk4 v0.3.0 (D:\gtk4-rs\gsk4)
   Compiling gtk4 v0.3.0 (D:\gtk4-rs\gtk4)
   Compiling study_rust v0.1.0 (C:\study_projects\study_rust)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in **42.35s**
```

Comment: What version of rustc?  Incremental compilation was disabled by default between [v1.52.1](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/05/10/Rust-1.52.1.html) and [v1.54.0](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/07/29/Rust-1.54.0.html#incremental-compilation-is-re-enabled-by-default).  Otherwise, might you have disabled [incremental](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#incremental) in your Cargo settings?

Comment: command "C:\study_projects\study_rust>rustc --version" show that version is 
rustc 1.55.0 (c8dfcfe04 2021-09-06), by the way, how can i know the rustc incremental compilication was eanbled ?

Comment: as far as I can tell, this is due to glib and others doing a code generation every re-build. I see that there are some advice elsewhere to run cargo with --no-deps, but I think that is a nightly feature? not present in my cargo.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to specify `build.incremental = true` for Cargo.

In the same folder of the `Cargo.toml` file, create the folder `.cargo`. Inside this `.cargo` folder, create the file `config.toml` with the following content:

```
[build]
incremental = true
```

Reference: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#buildincremental